# Python-Flask AJAX GET data does not display on HTML page

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have created a single page app using Python and Flask. The page has a "next" button. When the user clicks the "next" button I want to reload the page using data ('id2') that I send with the GET request.

Here's my problem: When I execute the GET request I can see that the AJAX data is being received by my Python controller function. But, the HTML page does not seem to refresh with the correct data (In the example below, "bar" is not passed to the HTML page.)

I believe that no new page is being sent to my browser.  The output in my terminal window below only shows a GET request.  Also, when I look at the network traffic in Chrome Dev tools, after I click the 'next' button, I only see a new get request, and no new page is sent to the browser.

Can someone please help me understand how to create a GET (or POST) request that triggers the server to serve a new HTML page that includes the data from the GET request?

Thanks!

My Python Controller:

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home_page():
    print 'new page requested'
    data = request.args.get('id2');
    if data != None:
        return render_template("index.html", article="foo")
    else: 
        return render_template("index.html", article="bar")
```

My HTML/Javascript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>{{ article }}</p>
    <button class="next" id="next">Next</button>

      <script>
        $("#next").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: '/',
              data: {id2: "{{ article }}"}
            });
        });
      </script>
</body>
```

Terminal Data:

```
new page requested
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Apr/2015 00:01:16] "GET /?id2=foo HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: What does your index.html look like?

Comment: Please do not use `!= None` but `is not None` instead. Also, it's much better to use the `tojson` filter if you want to put data inside JavaScript: `data: {id2: {{ article|tojson }}}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use AJAX to replace the entire DOM with the template being output from your Flask app you can simply do the following:

```
var nextArticle == 'foo';

$("#next").click(function() {
    $.get("/?id2=" + foo, function(data) {
        document.open('text/html');
        document.write(data);
        document.close();
        // recreate binding for your $("#next") button
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not tied to AJAX.  My broader question is: 'How do I refresh my page after the 'next' button is clicked, and include data entered in the page in my refreshed page?'  What's the best way to do this?